# Adding Header in ListView Android

Tags: android, xml, header, textview, android-linearlayout

Currently my xml code for listview is as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
    

</LinearLayout>
```

Now after each 5th item, I want to add a static header. So it is fixed. The xml code for the header is as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/list_header_title"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:paddingTop="2dip"  
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"  
        android:background="#008000"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"  
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Now how do I merge both? There are online articles on adding headers to list and section list view etc to do it programmatically. But mine is not so complicated.

It is fixed, after every fifth item in the list view, add a header. Any idea how I could merge the both set of codes above?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new project with 2 activities

In `activity_main1.xml` add this code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="text"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In `activity_main2.xml` add this code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="text"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
android:background="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your MainActivity.java file add this

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnTouchListener{

private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem("ListView item " + i);
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("Header " + i);
        }
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
 //Adapter Class
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
}
}
```

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then       run it

Answer (score 0):

To create a list with section or header refer this [http://danielme.com/tip-android-27-listview-con-secciones-o-cabeceras/][1]

[1]: http://danielme.com/tip-android-27-listview-con-secciones-o-cabeceras/ .